# web scraping data from tables

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape the annual income statement, balance sheet and cash flow of this page. `https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AIBM&fstype=ii&ei` and put it into a dataframe. As you can see you can change the data by clicking on different parts of the page. Can someone show me how to scrape the annual income statement? This what I have so far. I can see the data in the soup, but I don't know how to get to it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame()
url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AIBM&fstype=ii&ei'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5'}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Should It be in general or only for NYSE? And which data you would like to get from the annual income statement?

Comment: Just for this ticker. I would like the whole table for annual income statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you just use pandas's `read_html()` function? As a result you get a list of data frames (`df`), one for each table that can be displayed by clicking on the options (among them the annual income statement):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AIBM&fstype=ii&ei")
```

Comment: wow. I think that might work. If it does, it will be the worst 200 rep points i've spent. But still well worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The pandas read_html should so what you want but since you asked about bs4if you were to create the tables yourself  it can be done quite easily with bs4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AIBM&fstype=ii&ei'


def get_rows(table): 
    # pull the data from each row, ignoring rows with no text
    for row in table.select("tr"):
        row = [x.text.strip() for x in row.select("td")]
        if row:
            yield row


def get_tables():
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    # get all the tabes using the id selector
    for table in soup.select("#fs-table"):
        # create columns from th tags in the thead and get rows from helper
        yield pd.DataFrame(list(get_rows(table)), columns=[x.text.strip() for x in table.find("thead").find_all("th")])
```

Which will give you six table, you can see the first  if we call `next(get_tables())`:

```
In [4]: next(get_tables())
Out[4]: 
     In Millions of USD (except for per share items)  \
0                                            Revenue   
1                               Other Revenue, Total   
2                                      Total Revenue   
3                             Cost of Revenue, Total   
4                                       Gross Profit   
5             Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total   
6                             Research & Development   
7                          Depreciation/Amortization   
8           Interest Expense(Income) - Net Operating   
9                           Unusual Expense (Income)   
10                   Other Operating Expenses, Total   
11                           Total Operating Expense   
12                                  Operating Income   
13       Interest Income(Expense), Net Non-Operating   
14                     Gain (Loss) on Sale of Assets   
15                                        Other, Net   
16                                 Income Before Tax   
17                                  Income After Tax   
18                                 Minority Interest   
19                              Equity In Affiliates   
20                    Net Income Before Extra. Items   
21                                 Accounting Change   
22                           Discontinued Operations   
23                                Extraordinary Item   
24                                        Net Income   
25                               Preferred Dividends   
26      Income Available to Common Excl. Extra Items   
27      Income Available to Common Incl. Extra Items   
28                     Basic Weighted Average Shares   
29           Basic EPS Excluding Extraordinary Items   
30           Basic EPS Including Extraordinary Items   
31                               Dilution Adjustment   
32                   Diluted Weighted Average Shares   
33         Diluted EPS Excluding Extraordinary Items   
34         Diluted EPS Including Extraordinary Items   
35  Dividends per Share - Common Stock Primary Issue   
36                    Gross Dividends - Common Stock   
37        Net Income after Stock Based Comp. Expense   
38         Basic EPS after Stock Based Comp. Expense   
39       Diluted EPS after Stock Based Comp. Expense   
40                        Depreciation, Supplemental   
41                               Total Special Items   
42                    Normalized Income Before Taxes   
43           Effect of Special Items on Income Taxes   
44          Income Taxes Ex. Impact of Special Items   
45                     Normalized Income After Taxes   
46                 Normalized Income Avail to Common   
47                              Basic Normalized EPS   
48                            Diluted Normalized EPS   

   3 months ending 2015-12-31 3 months ending 2015-09-30  \
0                   22,059.00                  19,280.00   
1                           -                          -   
2                   22,059.00                  19,280.00   
3                   10,652.00                   9,844.00   
4                   11,407.00                   9,436.00   
5                    5,101.00                   4,465.00   
6                    1,362.00                   1,287.00   
7                       80.00                      73.00   
8                           -                          -   
9                       12.00                     112.00   
10                    -519.00                     -32.00   
11                  16,962.00                  15,659.00   
12                   5,097.00                   3,621.00   
13                          -                          -   
14                          -                          -   
15                       2.00                          -   
16                   5,099.00                   3,621.00   
17                   4,461.00                   2,962.00   
18                          -                          -   
19                          -                          -   
20                   4,461.00                   2,962.00   
21                          -                          -   
22                          -                          -   
23                          -                          -   
24                   4,464.00                   2,950.00   
25                          -                          -   
26                   4,460.00                   2,962.00   
27                   4,463.00                   2,950.00   
28                          -                          -   
29                          -                          -   
30                          -                          -   
31                          -                       0.00   
32                     972.84                     978.96   
33                       4.58                       3.03   
34                          -                          -   
35                       1.30                       1.30   
36                          -                          -   
37                          -                          -   
38                          -                          -   
39                          -                          -   
40                          -                          -   
41                          -                          -   
42                          -                          -   
43                          -                          -   
44                          -                          -   
45                          -                          -   
46                          -                          -   
47                          -                          -   
48                       4.87                       2.98   

   3 months ending 2015-06-30 3 months ending 2015-03-31  \
0                   20,813.00                  19,590.00   
1                           -                          -   
2                   20,813.00                  19,590.00   
3                   10,423.00                  10,138.00   
4                   10,390.00                   9,452.00   
5                    4,923.00                   5,022.00   
6                    1,300.00                   1,298.00   
7                       72.00                      79.00   
8                           -                          -   
9                      178.00                     285.00   
10                    -190.00                     -20.00   
11                  16,716.00                  16,762.00   
12                   4,097.00                   2,828.00   
13                          -                          -   
14                          -                          -   
15                     127.00                     173.00   
16                   4,224.00                   3,001.00   
17                   3,526.00                   2,416.00   
18                          -                          -   
19                          -                          -   
20                   3,526.00                   2,416.00   
21                          -                          -   
22                          -                          -   
23                          -                          -   
24                   3,449.00                   2,328.00   
25                          -                          -   
26                   3,526.00                   2,416.00   
27                   3,449.00                   2,328.00   
28                          -                          -   
29                          -                          -   
30                          -                          -   
31                          -                          -   
32                     986.70                     992.30   
33                       3.57                       2.43   
34                          -                          -   
35                       1.30                       1.10   
36                          -                          -   
37                          -                          -   
38                          -                          -   
39                          -                          -   
40                          -                          -   
41                          -                          -   
42                          -                          -   
43                          -                          -   
44                          -                          -   
45                          -                          -   
46                          -                          -   
47                          -                          -   
48                       3.56                       2.52   

   3 months ending 2014-12-31  
0                   24,113.00  
1                           -  
2                   24,113.00  
3                   11,251.00  
4                   12,862.00  
5                    5,375.00  
6                    1,320.00  
7                       93.00  
8                           -  
9                      578.00  
10                    -317.00  
11                  17,018.00  
12                   7,095.00  
13                          -  
14                          -  
15                          -  
16                   7,095.00  
17                   5,516.00  
18                          -  
19                          -  
20                   5,516.00  
21                          -  
22                          -  
23                          -  
24                   5,485.00  
25                          -  
26                   5,514.00  
27                   5,483.00  
28                          -  
29                          -  
30                          -  
31                          -  
32                     995.30  
33                       5.54  
34                          -  
35                       1.10  
36                          -  
37                          -  
38                          -  
39                          -  
40                          -  
41                          -  
42                          -  
43                          -  
44                          -  
45                          -  
46                          -  
47                          -  
48                       6.65
```

Or using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with xpaths:

```
 url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AIBM&fstype=ii&ei'

from lxml.etree import fromstring, HTMLParser
import pandas as pd


def get_rows(table):
    for row in table.xpath(".//tr"):
        row = row.xpath("./td/text()")
        if row:
            yield row


def get_tables():
    r = requests.get(url)
    xml = fromstring(r.content, HTMLParser())
    for table in xml.xpath("//table[@id='fs-table']"):
        yield pd.DataFrame(list(get_rows(table)), columns=[x.strip() for x in table.xpath(".//th/text()")])
```